# Why can I create an object with string literals but if generics comes into place, i can't?

Tags: typescript

I try to create an Object with string literals.

```js
export type MyType<T extends string> = {
  propFromMyType: T;
};

export type TypeWithGenericLiteral<T extends string> = {
  [P in `${T}_with_literal`]: number;
};
```

If my create functions does not use a generic type itself, it works fine:

```js
const create = (t: MyType<"example">): TypeWithGenericLiteral<"example"> => {
    const prop = `${t.propFromMyType}_with_literal` as const;

    return {
        [prop]: 777
    };
}
```

But if the create function contains a type T itself, it is falling apart:

```js
const create = <T extends string> (t: MyType<T>): TypeWithGenericLiteral<T> => {
    const prop = `${t.propFromMyType}_with_literal` as const;

    return {
        [prop]: 777
    };
}
```

Even when I change type T to a specific literal like that, it does not work:

```js
type action = "example"

export type MyType<T extends action> = {
  propFromMyType: T;
};

export type TypeWithGenericLiteral<T extends action> = {
  [P in `${T}_with_literal`]: number;
};


const create = <T extends action> (t: MyType<T>): TypeWithGenericLiteral<T> => {
    const prop = `${t.propFromMyType}_with_literal` as const;

    return {
        [prop]: 777
    };
}
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAjgTwiBBZZAVVIA82C4cIAdgCYDOCVcMAlmQOYB8CAvAgN7AIIQYUCADEhAWyy40ALgTYA3MAC+S0JFiIUaeXgDqDOAAsA4uRCMAxgBlDFgIYAbQsTClKNOoxbsuvfgDaAAoITAgABgAk3NjKAPoA7oZGcY52ME7hALpyZACu4gBGFkqqwOXg0PAIllBkdDUwIPakAIycCAAUcHJSePgAROD24hCOIAOsAJRy0iAGxmZkFgw26U6Dw6Pjk5zs-vw1dQ2Cwh1R3HAAdKeiEn1o8UnGqeuO4Qj2NLX1cGqHCCacDyMDIPD4AMOAVuOQQAHYERD+GVlOUAPRohAUKAgGhkKCIBKwADW6iqiB+DUsTRaIAATB0XCRyNQEEMwCMxhN2N1ejh+thprN9Mklis1qQMs5BXtwQDKYhbudotdbmIoJJ+Y9EslXpLMp9vsc-uUAUCQWCDpCENChBBYQi4UiECiEOVgBisTi8QSEESYKTKpojr9Gs1SABmRlEZkeWj0JhsLo9TBagiCma6NALUzmKy2fWOOmEXz7Z0KgR25WXG529WauZPXVpQsfL4huj-Q7m0Fy602mFyR3O13AIA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because it is not possible to know with which type parameter the function will be called. Have a look at the following example:

```
const propFromMyType: 'example' | 'foo' = 'example';

create2({ propFromMyType })
```

Expected result type will be:

```
type ResultType = TypeWithGenericLiteral<'example' | 'foo'>
// { example_with_literal: number; foo_with_literal: number; }
```